# iOS Swift Same code results in different date formats when run on iPad and iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I have an iPhone app which while testing on 1x/2x on iPad results in some unusual behavior.

iPad text field output: 25-Jul-2015 6:02 pm

iPhone text field output: Jul 25, 2015, 6:02 PM

My date format code is as below:

```
dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM/dd/yyyy HH:mm Z"    // Already tried adding dateFormat, still no help.
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on here? I want both of them to use the same format. 
Thank you.

Comment: Your devices may have different timezone. Verify in Settings/General/Lang and Region

Comment: @HoaParis Well, there was difference (24hr/12hr) but I made them both on same format. Also, they are both in same location. Moreover, I want the app to behave normally no matter what setting user have on his device.

Comment: @Pavan Jangid I tried that, didn't help. Its the same.

Comment: When I placed .dateformat below .timeStyle I got desired output

Comment: Jul/17/2015 19:08 PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you set your own date format via a string, you should not restrict it using date style or time style. You may use that if you not defining any custom date format.

You may comment on that two property.

HH -> will give you hours in 24hrs format.
If you prefer to have in 12hrs format then use -> hh

moreover, z will give you time zones value.
to get AM/PM you should use -> a

Change your date format to "MMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a"
And you will get a consistent output as  "Jul-17-2015 12:05 PM"

Answer (score -1):

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a"
```

the above code gives me formatted Date string